# Haskell Esqueleto: perform join on list of values using "with"

Tags: haskell, esqueleto

I am trying to do a join on a list of values known beforehand. In the following example - to get prices for each sku in the list.

I have found a link suggesting a use of "with" function:
https://funprog.srid.ca/haskell/values-in-esqueleto-persistent.html

But I am out of my depth here, don't know what to do. What is the simplest way to perform a join on a list of values? (Using CTE support and "with" - or in other way)

Here's my attempt (doesn't compile):

```
-- items :: [(SkuId, Int)]
-- itemsPrices :: [(SkuId, Int, Double)]

itemsPrices <- select $ do
   cte <- with $ do
      toAlias (val items)
   (sku :& price) <-
      from $ cte
      `InnerJoin` Table @Price
      `on` (\(sku :& price) ->
         price ^. PriceSku ==. val (fst <$> sku))
   pure (fst <$> sku, snd <$> sku, price ^. PriceValue)
```